# How to know client's Magento configuration

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have developed an open source magento Extension but it failed to install in client's Magento and crashed the whole magento.

But when I install the Magento Extension on my own fresh Magento installation it is working fine. I have no idea how to replicate the issue on my own Magento.

How can I know what is the cause for this. One way I can ask client to enable the System Logs or developer mode in the test environment and then install the Extension. Later on I can ask log files.

But how to make extension compatible for all or most of the Magento configurations.

Moreover is there any way to know the client's Magento Configuration and Extensions they have installed.

Comment: you could ask your client to check his apache logs. If his site is crashed, there probably is a php or mysql error that will be logged in /var/log/apache2/error.log. To replicate the issue, the best way would be to replicate his site in your local machine and install your extension

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rewriting of core classes, you need to use event-observer method wherever possible.
And regarding development environment, you can note the points from following article:
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-magento-for-development-debug-mode/

Thanks
Regards

Comment: I know all this but I can't do this for each and every client who use the extension. The problem is to make the extension robust and compatible for any type of magento configuration.

Comment: Well, that's the wrapper logic. You all need to find the related event that would be dispatched for your extension(for example if you are tracking visitor info then you need to collect  data by hooking into; controller_action_predispatch event) and write the event-observer code accordingly.